# Custom strtok function not working as expected

Tags: c, strtok

I was trying to write my own strtok function.

```
char * toke(char * out, char * in, char * destr) {
    int place = 0;
    for(int i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; i++){
        for(int d = 0; destr[d] != '\0'; d++){
            if(in[i] == destr[d]){
                printf("\nMatch.");
                place = i;
                i = 0;
                while(i < place){
                    out[i] = in[i];
                    i++;
                }
                out[place + 1] = '\0';
                i = place;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Program:

```
int main(){
    char * pr;
    char * o;
    char * in = "Hello-World";
    pr = toke(o, in, "-");
    printf(pr);
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps on seg-faulting and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: 1) `char * o;` --> `char o[16];` 2)`out[place + 1] = '\0';` --> `out[i] = '\0';`

Comment: 3) Logic is wrong overall probably.

Comment: BTW: I think you can get by with `for(int i = 0; ; i++){ for(int d = 0; ; d++){`  as eventually `in[i]` matches `destr[d]` when both are `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'out' pointer is not initialized and this:

```
out[i] = in[i];
```

throws the exception